# NSArray unwanted deallocation

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am new to collection programming , so i faced this problem . Any help will be thanked ...

I Initialized a NSArray instance in a class initialize ( i already define that as a property of that class in header file so i a must can access it any where in that class implementation  ) and assign some object to it with
`+(NSArray*) arrayWithObjects: ;` . every thing in init method is fine but ,...

When i want to work with that array in update method app crashs , because that array **DEALLOCATED** .

Why that array became deallocated ? How can i prevent it ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are initializing array like this,

```
objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: buttonOne, buttonTwo, 
                                     textField, nil];
```

its a conventional method, It just auto-release the object after one time the object access. Rather you can `retain` the object or you can allocate and initialize it like

```
objects = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: buttonOne, buttonTwo, 
                                     textField, nil];
```

Comment: assumes non-arc env. else this may not be a solution

Comment: @Daij-Djan Using `alloc` and `init` does not itself assume non-ARC.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using ARC, then you should init it with initWithObjects, then retain it.
If you are using ARC, probably it's just a weak reference.Make it be a strong reference when you declare the property.

Answer (score 1):

You should `alloc` NSArray and use `-initWithObjects` method instead.

`NSArray* tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(id), ..., nil]`

Comment: assumes non-arc env. else this may not be a solution